# JSON-LD context with array of objects

Tags: json, json-ld

I am trying to define a JSON-LD context that includes an array of objects.

Does anyone know, why the output is empty?

```
{
  "@context": {
     "testobjects": {
      "@id" : "http://example.org/arrayOfObjects",
      "type" : "array",
      "items" : {
        "type" : "object",
        "properties" : {
          "attr1": { "type" : "number", "default" : 1},
          "attr2": { "type" : "string", "default" : "foo"}
        }
      }
    }
  },

  "testobjects": [
    {
    "attr1": 216,
    "attr2": "test"
    },
    {
    "attr1": 329,
    "attr2": "test2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "http://example.org/arrayOfObjects": [
      {},
      {}
    ]
  }
]
```

See [JSON-LD Playground](http://json-ld.org/playground/#startTab=tab-expanded&json-ld=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22testobjects%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.org%2FarrayOfObjects%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22array%22%2C%22items%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22object%22%2C%22properties%22%3A%7B%22attr1%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22number%22%2C%22default%22%3A1%7D%2C%22attr2%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22string%22%2C%22default%22%3A%22foo%22%7D%7D%7D%7D%7D%2C%22testobjects%22%3A%5B%7B%22attr1%22%3A216%2C%22attr2%22%3A%22test%22%7D%2C%7B%22attr1%22%3A329%2C%22attr2%22%3A%22test2%22%7D%5D%7D) for trying yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Note that data does not go in a context, so having items as a part of the "testobjects" term definition won't do. There is a proposal to [allow multi-dimensional arrays to have individual types](https://github.com/json-ld/json-ld.org/issues/397), that may be taken up in the future.

For the example you've provided to generate anything, both "attr1" and "attr2" would need to be defined as terms at the top-level of the context, not under an existing context definition.